# TypeScript compile problem with Windows Script Host

Tags: typescript

i want to learn Angular and started with basics of typescript. I use Visual Studio Code, made first small thing:

console.log('Hello world');

and I wanted to compile it to js. I use "tsc hello.ts" and got this error:
[image]

I read that this isn't more supported, but can't find any working answer how currently I can compile ts to js. I've got node and typescript installed - added to path.

Answer (score 0):

Give this command to check typescript version

```
tsc --version
```

If it's giving version then typescript is installed properly but if it's not then install typescript using following command

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Give this command to check node version

```
node -v
```

if it's giving version then node is installed properly but if it's not then download nodejs setup and install it.

Compile your code using following commands, it should work.

```
tsc filename.ts
node filename.js
```